# getting correct objects from string parameter in factory

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, calculator

I've been trying to figure out if theres a way to pass a string to a factory or constructor and create the correct object without having to map the string to an object, or without having a bunch of if/else statements or switch statements.

Keep in mind, this is a simple example so I can apply what I learn to more complicated situations in web apps, etc.

let's take a simple calculator app, written in JAVA, as an example

---

assuming this is command line, and a person can pass in 3 values

```
- first number
- math operation (+ , - , / , x)
- second number
```

and we have an interface

```
public interface ArithmeticOperation {
  public double performMathOperation(double firstNum, double secondNum);
}
```

with 4 classes that implement it

```
public class AdditionOperation implements ArithmeticOperation {
  public double performMathOperation(double firstNum, double secondNum) {
    return firstNum + secondNum;
  }
}

// public class Subtraction operation returns firstNum - secondNum
// etc...
```

and we have our actual Calculator class and UserInput class

```
public class UserInput {
  public UserInput(double firstNum, double secondNum, String operation) {
    this.firstNum = firstNum;
    // etc...
  }
}
public class Calculator {
  public UserInput getInput() {
    // get user input, and return it as a UserInput object
    // return a UserInput object
  } 
  public performOperation() {
    UserInput uInput = getInput();
    double answer = ArithmeticOperationFactory
      .getSpecificOperation(uInput.operation)
      .performMathOperation(uInput.firstNum, uInput.secondNum);
    // send answer back to user
  }
}
```

finally, the place where the question mostly revolves around, the factory

```
public class ArithmeticOperationFactory {

  public static ArithmeticOperation getSpecificOperation(String operation) {
    // what possibilities are here?
    // I don't want a map that maps strings to objects
    // I don't want if/else or switch statements
    // is there another way?

  }
}
```

also, if theres a better way to architect a system like this or a design pattern that can be applied, please share. I'm really trying to learn some good object oriented design

Comment: I feel like a map would be the right choice for your operations. Why don't you want one?

Comment: @Zar assume there are 20 possible operations. Would a map still be ideal? I'd like a more dynamic approach if one exists. Otherwise, If I want to update/add new operations, I have to go and update the map every time

Comment: I think so. Somewhere you will have to have a list of supported operations, your program can't really "guess" them. You could extract them to a file you read or something to make it easier to change them.

Comment: If the mapping is dynamic, can you externalize the mapping and look it up at runtime and use reflection to instantiate the class?  We use this methodology for a rating engine.  All classes are defined in the datastore.  Then we look it up by the key value @ runtime.  New classes are added without impacting the factory

Comment: @purringpigeon interesting. That might be one possibility.

Comment: @Zar I see. yea, I mean i'd prefer a map over conditional logic for sure. Let's see what other answers people have

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it using `switch case`. This is [Factory Design Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm).

```
class ArithmeticOperationFactory {
  public static ArithmeticOperation getSpecificOperation(String operation) {
    switch (operation) {
      case "ADD":
        return new AdditionOperation();
      case "SUBTRACT":
        return new SubtractOperation();
      // You can define the rest of the operation here.
      default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("OPeratino is not supported: " + operation);
    }
  }
}
```

You can also define `Enum` for each operation and use them in `switch-case`.

Comment: thanks but I said in my question that I want a solution without conditional logic

Comment: This is `Factory Design Pattern`. Check [Design Pattern - Factory Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm). You have to use some conditional code for creating different objects.

Answer (score 1):

What are you asking for is a mapping operation because you have a String as input and you want an Object implementing and interface (ArithmeticOperation) back. If a mpa dose not fit you needs you must "configure" the mapping in a different way, this is my suggestion:
Change the interface to

```
public interface ArithmeticOperation {
    public double performMathOperation(double firstNum, double secondNum);
    public double getName();
}
```

Your add operation will result as the following one:

```
public class AdditionOperation implements ArithmeticOperation {
    public double performMathOperation(double firstNum, double secondNum) {
        return firstNum + secondNum;
    }
    public double getName() {
        return "+";
    }
```

}

In you method factory all you need is to find all the classes implementing the `ArithmeticOperation` interface; something like:

```
public class ArithmeticOperationFactory {
    private List<ArithmeticOperation> availableOperations=null;
    //to be called at application startup
    public static void findAvailableOperations() {
        // a strategy for finding implementations that fills
        // availableOperations
    }
public static ArithmeticOperation getSpecificOperation(String operation) {
  for (ArithmeticOperation arithmeticOperation : availableOperations) {
      if (operation.equalsIngoreCase(arithmeticOperation.getName)) {
         return arithmeticOperation;
      }
  }

}
```

Here are some method you can yous to implement findAvailableOperations:

If you are using Spring you can get the api `getBeansOfType` and retrieve all the implementations (I'm assuming you are configuring the concrete operations as Spring beans).

If you are not using spring you can scan the classpath in order to find the classes that implement your interface; you can start from [this project](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) or [this one](https://github.com/ddopson/java-class-enumerator).

Another solution is to put the implementation class names into a file (.properties, .xml, .json, etc), read the class names and create them via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different way.  I'm not sure it's better.

We have to go back to the interface and add another method so that the class can identify the operator.

```
public interface ArithmeticOperation {
    public boolean isOperator(String operator);
    public double performMathOperation(double firstNum, double secondNum);
}
```

We code the concrete methods like this:

```
public class AdditionOperation implements ArithmeticOperation {
    @Override
    public boolean isOperator(String operator) {
        return operator.equals("add");
    }

    @Override
    public double performMathOperation(double firstNum, double secondNum) {
        return firstNum + secondNum;
    }
}
```

We put all of the ArithmeticOperation classes in a List

```
List<ArithmeticOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
operations.add(new AdditionOperation());
...
```

Finally, we perform the operation like this.

```
double answer = 0D;
for (ArithmeticOperation operation : operations) {
    if (operation.isOperator(currentOperator) {
        answer = operation.performMathOperation(firstNum, secondNum);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method which is much better than solutions you have seen before. You can only make it slightly more elegant. In essence you can have:

Bunch of if/else/switch (probably least elegant but fast)

```
if("typeAsString").equals("operation"){
    return new SomeType()
}
```

---

Map

```
Map<String, Class<? extends YourType> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can make it bit better with dependency injection or you can make each subclass to add its own entry in this map. I'd favor keeping configuration away from factory class and moving it to subclasses.

---

Kind of chain of responsibility

You have to create `Collection` of all your subtypes. Each subtype has to have method like `isItCorrectSubtype()`. Client class has to iterate through whole collection and check which implementation is correct

```
@Autowired
List<InterfaceOfYourTypes> allSubtypes;

..

public void doStuff(){
    for(InterfaceOfYourTypes subtype: allSubtypes){
        if(subtype.isCorrectSubtype()){
            //create instance
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Factory like this

```
public class ArithmeticOperationFactory {
    public static ArithmeticOperation getSpecificOperation(String operation) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return (ArithmeticOperation) resolveClass(operation).newInstance();
    }

    private static Class resolveClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return Class.forName(className);
    }
}
```